# For loop in batch file stopping unwantedly

Tags: windows, batch-file, for-loop, executable

I have a batch file doing a for loop that looks something like this:

```
for /f %%F in ("%DIR%\*.xml") do something.exe --Option1=Value1 --Option2=Value2 ... --File="%%~fF"
```

where "something" is a not owned black box (don't know how it works, can't be modified) that performs certain operation. This runs correctly and returns a "completed successfully" message, however for some reasons it forces my for loop to stop and run the next line of my batch file without performing the operation for all the rest of the files.

Is there any way I can force it to continue and not exit the for loop?

Comment: `black box` - Do you mean by Command Prompt.

Comment: Remove the `/f` in the `for` command. You want to iterate over a set of files, not to read the contents of a file list nor process a single string (what you are doing in your code)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you want to loop through file names, remove the `/f` flag.

```
for %%G in ("%DIR%\*.xml") do ...
```

---

Since your `doSomething` program terminates after finishing it's work, you will need to start the `doSomething` on a separate process.

Simply change `doSomething "%%~fF"` to

```
start "" programName "%%~fF"
```